# List of 2D-arrays/matrices to 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a list of arrays with the length 3625, consisting of (101, 101) matrices/2D-arrays which I want to convert/reshape to a 2D array e.g. size (725, 5) or directly into a dataframe with the same size, so that each element in the this new list contains one of those 2d-arrays.

I tried it like this, also with np.ravel and reshape, but I can't seem to get it into the right shape.

```
list = np.zeros((725,5))
for i in y:
    list = np.append(list, [[i]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, please try to give more concrete examples. Anyway, as far as I understand you are looking for something like this.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.zeros((3625, 101, 101))
print(data.shape)
reshaped_data = np.reshape(data, (725, 5, 101, 101))
print(reshaped_data.shape)
```

Output:

(3625, 101, 101)

(725, 5, 101, 101)